# Где создавать index.php?

Tags: php, xampp

Только выучил html и css. Установил xampp, wordpress, но я не могу понять в какой папке собственно разрабатывать динамический сайт? Он же состоит из файлов php, а где их создавать? Например, где создать index.php? И где файлы css? html, в которых можно писать код страниц? В какой папке создавать php, css, html страницы? Объясните поподробней, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ваш вопрос тянет на диссертацию. Ищите в гугле уроки по php или читайте книги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от конфигурации apache но если у xampp дефолтные настройки то ищите в директории где установлен xampp директорию htdocs в котором и надо создавать php файлы. Расположение файлов по вашему желанию но не выше корня сайта (в вашем случае наверное htdocs). Например htdocs/index.php, htdocs/css/style.css, htdocs/mylibs/lib.php и т.д. Какая директория является корнем сайта нужно смотреть в httpd.conf (если нет виртуальных хостов) в параметре documentroot. Так же в httpd.conf есть параметр index в котором можно указывать что грузить index.php или index.html.

```
<Directory />
index index.php
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы новичок, я вам советую работать с денвером. На сайте myrusakov очень подробно все описано - сам учился. Денвер - это тоже самое, что и ксампп, только ксампп используют профи.

Вот ссылка на денвер : [оф.сайт](http://denwer.ru)
Вот ссылка на сайт обучения : [myrusakov,выбираете пункт php](http://myrusakov.ru)

А с ксампом не работал, извините)))

Comment: Разве денвер теперь стал нормальным wamp?

Comment: Ну, я им пользуюсь и не жалуюсь...

Comment: Как по мне, очень удобен и прост в испотльзовании

Comment: Либо OpenServer, либо какой-нибудь WAMP, denwer это совсем печальный путь.

Comment: нет, совсем нет